# Enabling ssl in socket stream app

Tags: node.js, ssl, socketstream

I'm writting a socket stream app in which i need it to work with ssl.

Googled it a while, found a [link](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream/issues/252), but the answer [link is broken](http://www.socketstream.org/tour)

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, found out we need to do like

```
var https = require('https')
,   options = {
       key : 'ssl key'
       , cert : 'ssl cert'
}
;

 var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

 });

ss.start(server.listen('8080'));
```